# Realtek ALC892: Crackling sound when starting music

Tags: sound, realtek

I'm using a board with Realtek ALC892 for music playback.
I installed the Realtek HDA drivers (3.0).
Using shairport-sync with hardware mixer.

Whenever I start audio playback I get a crackling noise first, as if the soundcard gets activated. Sounds like plugging in a headphone jack while speakers are on. Occurs after a few seconds of stopped playback, too, and sometimes, when altering the master or front volume from within alsamixer.

Any idea as to why this happens? Is it shairport-syncs fault?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit: The sound card somehow came in powersaving mode, and always activated / deactivated on starting / stopping playback. Deactivating the powersaving mode was the solution:
Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add before the `exit`-line:

`echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save`