# Extremely bad sound (crackling) on analog/headphones with Realtek ALC892 Codec

Tags: sound, headphones, realtek

i assembled a new PC based on a AM4 Platform. The [Mainboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B350-TOMAHAWK/Specification) provides a Realtek ALC892 Codec for audio.

Sometimes the sound gets very distorted (crackling noises). Since the last boot the problem is persistent.

I attached my headphones using a 3.5mm cable, when attaching the headphones directly the problem does still exist, so this is not the problem. When i attach the headphones to my android device the sound is perfect, so it has to be related to my setup here.

- Ubuntu Version is 16.04.3
- Kernel: 4.10.0-42-generic

I allready checked [this related quesion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594552/realtek-alc892-crackling-sound-when-starting-music), but that did not work.

The sound is like someone is constantly twisting the cable. It is extremely annoying :-(

**UPDATE 2018-02-06:**

Did not find any solution so far, the situation is unchanged (kernel @ 4.13.0-32-generic).

I noticed, that the crackling starts about 1 hour after i booted and persists for about 15 minutes. It will not happen multiple times in one work-day - only once. Rebooting helps, but i cant reboot all the time...

**UPDATE 2018-03-28:**

Very strange: Today the same problem occured on a different machine. This machine has a Creative Soundblaster SB0730 soundcard connected via PCI because the integrated audio is broken. Everything worked perfectly until today - when suddenly the sound began to freak out.

Its a dualboot setup, so i booted into windows to see if the soundcard causes the crackling but windows plays all sounds perfectly.

This problem is really really weird. Both systems are AMD-based, this system is a AM3+ Platform with a AMD FX-8320, Mainboard = ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0.

Same Ubuntu version, same Kernel, so it might be connected...

**UPDATE 2018-06-05:**

No change, but it seems to happen less often now
Kernel: 4.13.0-43-generic

Comment: I have this now, kernel 4.18, Debian 9. Any success? You mean even a separate sound card didn't help you?

Comment: No, i did not find any solution so far. But i did not check for a long time, i currently work on a notebook where that problem does not occur. A strange thing i noticed is, that the crackling sometimes stopped when i killed certain processes (docker, virtualbox, everything related to virtualization). Maybe completely random but who knows...

Comment: The problem happened when an application used mic. Just playback (wihtout mic) was ok. The only thing I came up with was buying a sound card supported in Linux. This will save me from such problems in future.

Comment: When crackling starts, I change the audio output device, or speaker configuration. It generally fixes it temporarily...

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this issue? Supposedly the problem can be fixed by disabling "auto-mute". Use the command *alsamixer* and ensure your terminal window is widened so the option shows, then navgate to it with the arrow keys. I think up/down disables it. There are some that say this doesn't work though so I'm sorry if it doesn't fix the issue.